# How to open all dynamically loaded tabs in a PrimeFaces Accordion Panel

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am loading the contents of a table into an PrimeFaces 4.0 Accordion Panel, with each row corresponding to a dynamically loaded tab. I can do this, but only the first tab is open by default.

Normally, to have multiple Accordion Panels open by default you use `activeIndex="tabIndexList"`, where `tabIndexList` is the list of tabs you want open.

For instance:

```
<p:accordionPanel multiple ="true" activeIndex="0,1,2">
```

But when dynamically loading tabs using database table rows it's not possible to know how many tabs there will be when writing the html code.

Is there a setting built into PrimeFaces to allow all tabs to be open by default or is it possible to used a backing bean to calculate and pass the require string for `activeIndex`, using something like below?

```
<p:accordionPanel multiple ="true" activeIndex="#{backingBean.returnActiveIndexString}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until the actual latest version of PrimeFaces (4.0) there's no such feature to open all tabs. But your approach would work if the backing bean returns a String with all the indices of the Collection.

Like:

```
public String returnActiveIndexString(){
    totalNumberOfTabs = getTotalNumberOfTabs();
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    String prefix = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < totalNumberOfTabs; i++){
        out.append(prefix);
        prefix = ",";
        out.append(i);
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

Comment: you return a StringBuilder here when a String is expected. Moreover I get the exception `The class 'BackingBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy' does not have the property 'returnActiveIndexString'.`

Comment: @dasLort I didn't had all the back bean code, so I just gave a way to resolve it. This probably is happening because you don't have adapt the code to you bean. You probably is having this error because of the lack of the parameter on the method call.

Answer (score 0):

for me it was important that a click event is triggered because i have to initialize some data on click so i solved it this way: 1. Close all tabs by setting the activeTabindex to "-1", 2. Click every tab. the p:accordionPanel needs to have the attribute multiple="true".

```
<p:commandButton value="open"
        actionListener="#{beanController.setActiveTabIndex('-1')}"
        update="accordionPanel"
        oncomplete="$('.ui-accordion-header').click();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just wanted to show all tabs for printing.

Updating the CSS class dynamically was the best approach.

Here is how to do it with JQuery:

```
<span onclick="$('.ui-accordion-content.ui-helper-hidden').css('display','block')" >
  Printable version
</span>
```

Comment: Why not add that in a CSS with media type print?

Comment: Yes, I will probably do that too, but I actually wanted also an Expand / Collapse link, to allow the user to toggle all at once, and without touching the java beans.